# C# Revit PostCommand DetailLine Change option

Tags: c#, revit-api

If I use the DetailLine function using an API called PostCommand, is there a way to access the option value called Chain to give, fix, or change the default value?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mdsmd.png)

I looked up the Rabbit API, but there was no related data

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Revit API [`PostCommand` method](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2023/b0df464d-1733-ea9e-ac40-399fa9c9a037.htm) enables you to launch some built-in Revit UI commands. It does not provide any functionality whatsoever to influence their behaviour. The user has to interact with them just like in the standard UI.

No idea what you mean by Rabbit API.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. :) 

 When using the DetailLine function using PostCommand's method, can I set the option value called Chain as a code in advance as shown in the picture?

Comment: RevitCommandId cmd = RevitCommandId.LookupPostableCommandId(PostableCommand.DetailLine);

uiapp.PostCommand(cmd) ;

Comment: Can I code the option value in the Detail Line function before or after PostCommand and prevent the user from changing it? It's when I draw with Line from Detail Line.
The name of the option is Chain.

Comment: No, sorry. `PostCommand` just launches the built-in UI functionality. Nothing more whatsoever. No options, settings, arguments, of any kind whatsoever.